# Prometheus : Text format parsing error in line 1696: invalid metric name in comment

Tags: mongodb, dropwizard, hystrix, prometheus

I am trying to use promethues for reporting executes Hystrix commands for mongo db,Everything is working fine except promethues not able to understand below line and shows the target state as down.

# HELP rideshare-engine_hystrix_command_latency_total_percentile_995 DEPRECATED: Rolling percentiles of execution times for the end-to-end execution of HystrixCommand.execute() or HystrixCommand.queue() until a response is returned (or ready to return in case of queue(). The purpose of this compared with the latency_execute* percentiles is to measure the cost of thread queuing/scheduling/execution, semaphores, circuit breaker logic and other aspects of overhead (including metrics capture itself).

[image: Error]
complete stack 
[image]

Not sure what Am a doing wrong here

Config:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hypens are not valid in Prometheus metric names, use underscore instead.